# Как исправить в ExportToWord.inc на open server ошибку?

Tags: php

Ошибка `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\OSPanel\domains\web-server\html_to_doc-master\ExportToWord.inc.php on line 122`

https://github.com/Korchy/html_to_doc

На хостинге всё нормально работает, а вот на Open Server 5.2.2 такая беда.
Подскажите пожалуйста что может быть и как с этим бороться?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего в Open Server 5.2.2 используется не очень свежая версия php, которая не поддерживает объявление массивов вида $a = [], а на хостинге у вас вполне актуальная, и там с этим проблем нет оптимальным решением будет использование php > 5.5.